# Add an array to an array list

Tags: arrays, powershell, arraylist, casting

OK, I am going to rephrase the question to be both more generic and more complete. But I am leaving the original post at the bottom.

Given: a variable `$queue`, which I want to add different kinds and sizes of collections to, and those collections could be locally created variables, or results passed from a function.
I want to avoid `+=` when dealing with `$queue`, so a simple array is not an option.
I need to be able to add collections of variable sizes, so support for `.AddRange()` is desired since it can work with single item collections and larger collections.
I need to support Windows 7/PS2 as well as Windows 10/PS5
`[System.Collections.ArrayList]` has been deprecated, so that's not ideal.
This leaves `System.Collections.Generic.List[string]` as the type for `$queue`
Also, there are maybe a few hundred at most places where I need to add to `$queue`, but potentially over 1000 places where the various other collections are defined. So making all those other collections also use `System.Collections.Generic.List[string]` would be really problematic. Even just casting before returning would be a ton of work. So I really want to keep the intervention within `$queue.AddRange()`.
This is also a short term refactor and bug fix release (some of the bugs are related to this stuff), before a ground up rewrite as Classes, where 100% of these collections will be `System.Collections.Generic.List[string]`, and there will be a LOT less redundant code.
Also, the desire is for the simplest, most readable code now, to make that rewrite as easy as possible.

So, ideally this would work

```
$queue = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]

$array1 = @('array1.1')
$array3 = @('array3.1', 'array3.2', 'array3.3')
$arrayList1 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@('arrayList1.1')
$arrayList3 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@('arrayList3.1', 'arrayList3.2', 'arrayList3.3')
$genericList1 = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]@('genericList1.1')
$genericList3 = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]@('genericList3.1', 'genericList3.2', 'genericList3.3')

function ReturnArray ([int]$count) {
    $return = @()
    foreach ($i in 1..$count) {
        $return += "ArrayFunction$($count).$($i)"
    }
    return $return
}

function ReturnArrayList ([int]$count) {
    $return = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    foreach ($i in 1..$count) {
        $return.Add("ArrayListFunction$($count).$($i)") > $null
    }
    return $return
}

function ReturnGenericList ([int]$count) {
    $return = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
    foreach ($i in 1..$count) {
        $return.Add("GenericList[string]Function$($count).$($i)")
    }
    return $return
}

CLS
$queue.AddRange($array1)
$queue.AddRange($array3)

$queue.AddRange($arrayList1)
$queue.AddRange($arrayList3)

$queue.AddRange($genericList1)
$queue.AddRange($genericList3)

$returnValue = ReturnArray 1
$queue.AddRange($returnValue)
$returnValue = ReturnArray 3
$queue.AddRange($returnValue)

$returnValue = ReturnArrayList 1
$queue.AddRange($returnValue)
$returnValue = ReturnArrayList 3
$queue.AddRange($returnValue)

$returnValue = ReturnGenericList 1
$queue.AddRange($returnValue)
$returnValue = ReturnGenericList 3
$queue.AddRange($returnValue)

$queue
```

This is problematic on a number of fronts. When a single element array is returned from a function, it's unrolled, so `.AddRange()` doesn't work. But I want to avoid re-arraying everything like this

```
$queue.AddRange(@($variable))
```

In Windows 10 casting everything to `[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]` like this works, and with a Type Accelerator it would even be readable. But this fails in Windows 7/PS2.

```
$queue.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$array1)
$queue.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$array3)

$queue.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$arrayList1)
$queue.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$arrayList3)

$queue.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$genericList1)
$queue.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$genericList3)

$returnValue = ReturnArray 1
$queue.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$returnValue)
$returnValue = ReturnArray 3
$queue.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$returnValue)

$returnValue = ReturnArrayList 1
$queue.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$returnValue)
$returnValue = ReturnArrayList 3
$queue.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$returnValue)

$returnValue = ReturnGenericList 1
$queue.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$returnValue)
$returnValue = ReturnGenericList 3
$queue.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$returnValue)
```

So, the question in a nutshell is; is there a single, readable, performant way to make this work in both Win7/PS2 & Win10/PS5? Frustratingly, it seems like using `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` is actually a bit easier. But, between deprecation and `.Add()` polluting the pipeline, which occurs in a lot of the functions, that isn't an option either.

Hopefully that clarifies the scope of the problem.

Original Post

---

I am in the process of refactoring some code to use generic lists vs array, as some of the arrays are getting large and I prefer `.Add()` and `.AddRange()` to `+=`.

However, I have a LOT of code, and I will likely not be able to refactor everything at once. So I will have some places where arrays need to be added to array lists, sometimes with the array coming from a function. My sense is that the best approach for now is just to cast the array to an array list at the point where I am adding, such as...

```
$list.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$array)
```

Then, once I have every instance of simple array use replaced, I can return to clean up the unnecessary casts. Is that my best way forward, or am I missing an easier answer?

Also, on a related note, it seems to me that defining my own type accelerator, with

```
$Accelerators = [PowerShell].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")
$Accelerators::Add("PxStringList","System.Collections.Generic.List[string]")
```

might be a good idea. Since

```
$list.AddRange([PxStringList]$array)
```

is easier to read than

```
$list.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$array)
```

Again, am I on the right track, or missing something obvious?

EDIT: In case someone is wondering about the failure mode, this is a snippet of the code that raised the issue for me. This fails in Windows 7 & Windows 10.

```
$validFontExtentions = @('.ttf', '.txt')
$fontQueue = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$fontQueue.AddRange($validFontExtentions)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen, the question is, is casting when I do the AddRange the best way to deal with possible arrays being added? As JosefZ points out, one can unroll whatever you are adding, but my sense there is that the case is more readable, and it is a short term need. But even for a short term solution, I wan t to do it right.

Comment: `$fontQueue.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[string]]$validFontCollection)`

Comment: @JosefZ, what is the difference between `Generic.List` & `Generic.IEnumerable`? The examples I have seen all mention List only. Well, or they mention `[arralylist]`, which I hear is deprecated, so I am trying to avoid that too.

Comment: Also, it seems I may have an issue in PS 2.0. where none of this works. And at least for a little while longer I need to support 2.0. :(

Comment: If `$list` is an `ArrayLIst` it doesn't matter - if, on the other hand `$list` is a generic collection, it'll generally accept any `IEnumerable<T>`, including flats arrays, so you can make due with `$list.AddRange([string[]]$array)`, or if your don't know the type parameter: `$list.AddRange($array -as "$($list.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0])[]")`. Question is still unclear to me though, what is _the exact problem_ we're trying to solve here?

Comment: I cast `$validFontCollection` to type required by  _OverloadDefinitions_: see output from `$fontQueue.AddRange`.

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen I rephrased to be more generic and more complete. I'm not sure I succeeded. :)

Comment: That's a big wall of text, which is hard to read. Just a reminder, every question and every answer has an [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61756527/revisions). Therefor, there is no need to emphasize edits with `EDIT: ...` or leave entire old versions of the question inside the actual question, which mainly duplicates its content. Make your question concise, complete, easy to read and easy to understand. Do not risk wasting other peoples time and you will more likely get helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with [Adamt8's answer is the implicit type coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7214779/adamt8). The appended-to $arrList2 in his example becomes an Array, and you end up losing all the advantages of an ArrayList. The answer is **[<ArrayList>.addRange(<ICollection>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.addrange?view=net-8.0#system-collections-arraylist-addrange(system-collections-icollection))**. Examples follow:

Starting with his basic setup, using the `<ArrayList> += <Object[]>` syntax:

```
PS C:\> $arr = ("a","b","c")

PS C:\> $arr
a
b
c

PS C:\> $arrList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

PS C:\> $arrList.count
0

PS C:\> $arrList += $arr

PS C:\> $arrList.count
3
```

As you can see, we DO get the elements of the array added one-by-one to the ArrayList. However, looking at the type, we get a nasty surprise: the type has changed to `Object[]`

```
PS C:\> $arrList.getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                      
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Re-initializing the ArrayList and using the .addRange() method:

```
PS C:\> $arrList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

PS C:\> $arrList.getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                      
True     True     ArrayList                                System.Object                                                                                                                 



PS C:\> $arrList.addRange($arr)

PS C:\> $arrList.count
3

PS C:\> $arrList.getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                      
True     True     ArrayList                                System.Object
```

We can see that not only have all the elements of the array been added one-by-one, but the $arrList variable still contains an `ArrayList` object.

Answer (score -1):

If I've understood your problem statement, you basically want to add an existing list or array to another list, instead of having to enumerate and add one at a time.  I had the same problem and solved it with the following.

TL/DR:  use an ArrayList and the += operator instead of .Add

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $arr1 = ("a","b","c")
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $arr1
a
b
c
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $arr2 = ("d","e","f")
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $arr2
d
e
f
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $arrList = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $arrList.Add($arr1)
0    <=== CLUE
```

Here is a clue:  There is only one index given as an output of .Add, even though we know there are 3 elements that should be added.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $arrList
a
b
c
```

But when you output the arraylist, it looks like 3 elements.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $arrList | % {"another one: $_"}
another one: a b c
```

But when you iterate with foreach, it becomes obvious you added one element with whitespace.

But if you use +=, you will see that array is actually added one item at a time.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $arrList2 = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $arrList2 += $arr1
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $arrList2
a
b
c
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $arrList2 | % {"another one: $_"}
another one: a
another one: b
another one: c
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $arrList2 += $arr2
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $arrList2 | % {"another one: $_"}
another one: a
another one: b
another one: c
another one: d
another one: e
another one: f
```

Here we added two different arrays of 3 elements each to ArrayList2, and the result is a list that contains 6 individual elements.

Comment: A much better way is to use $arrList.addRange($arrayToAdd). The way Powershell works, the += operator coerces the arrayList on the left-hand side to an array. Use $arrListVariable.GetType() to see for yourself.